# Constraint Layout in android programming

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, constraints

[image: Screen shot of issue]

I am using Android new Layout Constraint Layout. I am facing an issue which is all the textviews body has hide and i am seeing constraints only.If any one knows how to solve this problem.Please tell me.
Image attached above showing an issue about body of textviews.

Regards

Comment: It was Layout Editor issue, after restarting android studio, it is working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor
this page will be helpful for your query.

Comment: It was Layout Editor issue, after restarting android studio, it is working fine now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs  regarding the Constraint Layout sometimes the views do not show or texts messing and all , just clean and rebuild the project or restart the Android Studio.